# constructor with non essential vars

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if it is possible and if so how, to create a constructor that takes three variables but will not through an error if the last two are not passed?

something like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String s1<non essential>) 
    {
```

Comment: your method defination shows only two args

Comment: onCreate() is a method, not a constructor.  Given the signature you have for it, you are writing an Android Activity.  In which case, you cannot change the argument list of onCreate, you have to keep it the same as when you got it.

Answer (score 12):

Create more contructors

```
public MyCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

public MyCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String s1) 
    {

public MyCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String s1, String s2) 
    {
```

try to read this [article](http://leepoint.net/JavaBasics/oop/oop-45-constructor-overloading.html) on constructor overloading.

Comment: And if possible, make one of the constructors the "main" one, and have the others just delegate to `this(savedInstanceState, DEFAULT_S1, DEFAULT_S2...)`. That way, if your constructor does change, you have less code to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways of doing this. To name a few:

- **You can have multiple constructors with different signatures** (as
  suggested by dash1e)
- **You can have List of the type of variables you want** (or of
  Objects, in case you want it to be fully generic), and have a
  constructor which takes the list and uses its values when present.
- **You can have a custom data model class to encapsulate the three

  types of values you want to deal with and use it in constructor**,
  making it so that when its values are being fetched by the
  constructor of your class, they are optional for the arguments    you
  want.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [dash1e's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036352/348975) best.  [Luis Miguel Serrano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036416/348975) has some excellent additional suggestions.

In addition - if appropriate - you can use varargs

```
public MyCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String ... args)
```

which has the same effect as

```
public MyCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String [ ] args )
```

it is very similar to Luis Miguel Serrano of using a List but you don't have to go to the hassle of creating a List.